# Jquery tab resets immediately when I click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I'm generating a tab set programmatically like so:

```
$statusTabs = $("<div class='statusTabs' id='statusTabs'></div>");
$headers = $("<ul>" + 
    "<li><a href='#awaitingApprovalTab'>    Awaiting Approval   </a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#pendingTab'>             Pending             </a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#approvedTab'>            Approved            </a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#changesRequiredTab'>     Changes Required    </a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#changesSubmittedTab'>    Changes Submitted   </a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#duplicateTab'>           Duplicate           </a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#deniedTab'>              Denied              </a></li>" +
    "</ul>");

$awaitingApproval = $("<div class='group' id='awaitingApprovalTab'></div>");
$pending =          $("<div class='group' id='pendingTab'></div>");
$approved =         $("<div class='group' id='approvedTab'></div>");
$changesRequired =  $("<div class='group' id='changesRequiredTab'></div>");
$changesSubmitted = $("<div class='group' id='changesSubmittedTab'></div>");
$duplicate =        $("<div class='group' id='duplicateTab'></div>");
$denied =           $("<div class='group' id='deniedTab'></div>");

$statusTabs.append($headers);
$statusTabs.append($awaitingApproval);
$statusTabs.append($pending);
$statusTabs.append($approved);
$statusTabs.append($changesRequired);
$statusTabs.append($changesSubmitted);
$statusTabs.append($duplicate);
$statusTabs.append($denied);

$statusTabs.tabs();
```

When I click on the "Approved" tab (the third one in the row), it immediately resets back to the first tab.  I can see a flash of content, so I know the contents of the Approved tab are being generated properly, and it let's me see them for a brief moment, but it jumps back to the first tab super-fast.  Anyone see what I messed up here?  All of the other tabs work perfectly fine as expected.

Comment: Can you tell us the line where the jQuery UI tab() function is called? Do you make sure to call it after the tabs are being generated?

Comment: Why are you appending the tabs twice, and one of those is before they exist...?

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can recreate the problem and not speculate.

Comment: I edited in the tab call, just a flat .tabs().  Editing out the double copy, that was a copy/paste goof

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/dwq1vgqL/ . Your code doesn't show DOM insertion, I had to add that

Comment: But then it's obviously inserted into the dom, given the problem description :)  I'm combing through other js on the page to see if there's a name conflict or something.  Interestingly, if I type #approvedTab into the url (e.g. localhost/home/#approvedTab) all of the tabs work perfectly.  Any idea what that changes about things to make it work?